# Choosing optimal number of clusters, graph not "elbowing" out and clusters after PCA & TSNE not coherent

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, pca, recommendation-engine

I am working on a post recommendation system. It has a title and category for each post. I used the category and implemented tf-idf to extract keywords and applied mini-batch k means for clustering.

```
def find_optimal_clusters(data, max_k):
    iters = range(5,max_k+1, 5)
    sse = []
    for k in iters:
        sse.append(MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k,
                                   init_size=512, 
                                   batch_size=1024,
                                  random_state=20).fit(data).inertia_)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot(iters, sse, marker='o')
    ax.set_xlabel('Cluster Centers')
    ax.set_xticks(iters)
    ax.set_xticklabels(iters)
    ax.set_ylabel('SSE')
    ax.set_title('SSE by Cluster Center Plot')

find_optimal_clusters(matrix, 250)
```

The graph is somewhat like this.
[Link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oqr.png)

Plot for the clusters, by PCA and TSNE, are:
[Left is PCA and right is TSNE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqIJn.png)

code for same:

```
def plot_tsne_pca(data, labels):
    max_label = max(labels)
    max_items = np.random.choice(range(data.shape[0]), size=500, replace=True)

    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data[max_items,:].todense())
    tsne = TSNE().fit_transform(PCA(n_components=50).fit_transform(data[max_items,:].todense()))


    idx = np.random.choice(range(pca.shape[0]), size=500, replace=True)
    label_subset = labels[max_items]
    label_subset = [cm.hsv(i/max_label) for i in label_subset[idx]]

    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 6))

    ax[0].scatter(pca[idx, 0], pca[idx, 1], c=label_subset)
    ax[0].set_title('PCA Cluster Plot')

    ax[1].scatter(tsne[idx, 0], tsne[idx, 1], c=label_subset)
    ax[1].set_title('TSNE Cluster Plot')

plot_tsne_pca(matrix, clusters)
```

There's no elbow per se except one at ~225 cluster, which seems a huge amount of clusters and they are already not coherent after I read through the top keywords of each cluster.
How should I go about this?